# Java version, Tomcat, Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am working on an app and I built the back end part with Java and Jersey which is hosted on my server. I use Tomcat7 on the server to be able to call the web services.

I had a previous computer with Ubuntu, I used to export my project to a war file, put it in the Tomcat folder and it worked. I now changed my computer to a Mac, I have the exact same Java project, which works when I run it locally on my computer. But when I upload it to the server the same way as before, I have this error : `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`.

I checked many websites and understood it was a Java Version problem. So I tried many changes but it didn't work.

- On my server I have : Ubuntu, tomcat7 and java-7-openjdk-amd64. In /etc/default/tomcat7, there's a line : `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64.`
- On my previous computer (Ubuntu), I used Eclipse and Java 8. And the generated war worked with the server.
- On my new computer (Mac), I also use Eclipse and Java 8 but the war files won't work on the server.

I tried to change the version of the compiler in Eclipse to Java 1.7 but I still have the same error.

Does anybody have any idea to fix this problem ? Thanks in advance for help

All the best.

Comment: Q: Can you recompile the offending code?  Q: Can you target Java7 for your recompile?  IDEAL SOLUTION: 1) Start Eclipse and open your project 2) `Project > Properties > Java Compiler > set Compatibility to 1.7`, 3) Rebuild and Redeploy.

Comment: For which exactly class do you get this error?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have this error when i set the Project Java Compiler to 1.7

`Description Resource Path Location Type Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet.`

Comment: I also changed the Project Facets and it now works ! Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 4):

Classfile version 52.0 means Java 8. You will need to install Java 8 on your server to read this file (or rebuild the jar, targeting Java 7).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the answers, I managed solving the issue. For those who encounter the same problem, this is the solution that worked for me :

`Project > Properties > Java Compiler > set Compatibility to 1.7`

`Project > Properties > Project Facets > set Java to 1.7`

Thank you all ! And I hope it will help other people.

Comment: Thank you. Someone use newer Java version and after getting SVN update I couldn't run my code. This way solves my problem.